# NameError during Scan hbase table

Tags: database, hbase

I'm trying to scan the table Employee(already created in hbase).
But i get error saying NameError. But name of table created in hbase and in commands matches. what could be the possible error?

Below is the snippet from the termnal:

hbase(main):001:0> list
TABLE
ARCHIVE_CALMAIL
ARCHIVE_USERSYNC
CALMAIL_DELETE_RECORDS
CAL_MAIL
CAL_MAIL_ARCHIEVE
CAL_MAIL_DELETE
CAL_MAIL_IOT
CONTACT_DETAILS
CONVERSATIONS
Customer
DIFF_SYNC
**Employee**
**EmployeeInfo**
FAILED_REQUESTS
GENERAL_INFO
LOGIN_MASTER
ORGANIZATION_ASSETS
ORGANIZATION_JOBS....
....
....

> hbase(main):002:0> scan **EmployeeInfo**
>   NameError: uninitialized constant EmployeeInfo
>
> hbase(main):003:0> scan **Employee**
>   NameError: uninitialized constant Employee

Both tables are already created in Database and also contains some data.
But both gets same error.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of HBase you are using? Did you put your table name within single quotes during scan like scan 'Employee' ?

Comment: @SubashKunjupillai  1] hbase version is 1.2.4 .  2] no i did not used single quotes while using scan.

Comment: For all operations on a table, you need to put the table name within single quotes.

Comment: @SubashKunjupillai   but earlier it all worked(without using single quotes) I got this error only for last time. I wanted to perform some operations on tables and it showed the above error. I am not able to find the reason behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the syntax for the scan command. I'm using HBase 1.1.8, and the recommended way to scan a table is by putting it within the quotes as shown in the help. Because then only it will be considered as an argument, else HBase shell will search for a class implementation.

[image]